# Issue with calling aws web apis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to implement AWS Push notifications in my mobile application using GCM. As part of registering the GCM token with AWS, I am trying to create the endpoint with AWS using API [CreatePlatformEndpoint] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformEndpoint.html. As part of calculating the Signature, i am following below website

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html#API_SignatureSampleCode

I have used below code for creating Signature Version for AWS

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AuthJavaSampleSig2.html

I am able to create below URL

http://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&Action=CreatePlatformEndpoint&CustomUserData=Rajan&PlatformApplicationArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-west-2%3A798120381702%3Aapp%2FGCM%2FAndroidMobilePushApp&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-07-04T18%3A35%3A27Z&Token=APA91bHKDGeNTMfCCdy1wetqxAu2yePhrkDb3KZIdYxJD1VoBnN4yh0CCw_WiAUd-MKM4eqjHixIswvMNMAa0FFByTeG0GcitHuqaP6IIMDiSvcbl-jV8jVoAjPufbWUEtDTA-0E8SmTacaLeBrZ-LCTzk65UOzsiunE75M-UalPro6p4bcSpj4&Version=2010-03-31&Signature=zPM6rDK9BhsaMLD5csiAqO6j30tVJ76Yy6FMcOzc4B4%3D%0A

Here is the response i got.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>f00722e6-d9cb-5747-ab51-6ed62f2d6b75</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Can someone guide what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lot of debugging, i could resolve the issue and the issue was very simple :( ...

It was not a POST request. It had to be a GET request only. I don't know why the documentation shows it to be a POST request.

Comment: Don't forget to up vote and/or accept any answers or comments that may have been helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should't have a `%0A` at the end of your signature. Don't know where you get it from.

Comment: The hmac signature = f34bw9/GyHmIvzWUgR8Ly4QcO2DprVos7Ww6nRTXZZk=
which is then URL encoded and converted to f34bw9%2FGyHmIvzWUgR8Ly4QcO2DprVos7Ww6nRTXZZk%3D%0A

Comment: Text which is send to hmac function is POST
sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
/
AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXZ5T7QOSOA&Action=CreatePlatformEndpoint&CustomUserData=Rajan&PlatformApplicationArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-west-2%3A798120381702%3Aapp%2FGCM%2FAndroidMobilePushApp&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-07-05T15%3A01%3A25Z&Token=APA91bHKDGeNTMfCCdy1wetqxAu2yePhrkDb3KZIdYxJD1VoBnN4yh0CCw_WiAUd-MKM4eqjHixIswvMNMAa0FFByTeG0GcitHuqaP6IIMDiSvcbl-jV8jVoAjPufbWUEtDTA-0E8SmTacaLeBrZ-LCTzk65UOzsiunE75M-UalPro6p4bcSpj4&Version=2010-03-31

Comment: The URL-encoded version of `f34bw9/GyHmIvzWUgR8Ly4QcO2DprVos7Ww6nRTXZZk=` is `f34bw9%2FGyHmIvzWUgR8Ly4QcO2DprVos7Ww6nRTXZZk%3D`. There should not be a `%0A`.

Comment: %0A is getting added while URL encoding the hmac id.

Comment: @RajanPhatak, well, it shouldn't. It means that whatever is passed to the encoding function has a linefeed at the end, which it shouldn't. So it's either your base64 encoding that adds a linefeed when it shouldn't, or something else adds the linefeed between the base64 encoding and the URL-encoding. Didn't you mistakenly add a linefeed while debugging? Otherwise just check if the base64 output has a linefeed at the end, and remove it before URL-encoding it.

Comment: I figured out the problem with %0A. It was a problem with respect to Base64 encoder which i was using from Android. After changing the Base64 encoder to Apache (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64) Issue with %0A is resolved. However still response remains the same.

Comment: @RajanPhatak, in the original post you give a full GET URL, when it's supposed to be a POST operation (i.e. the URL should be just `http://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/`, and the rest of the data should be passed in the body of the POST).

Comment: I am still getting the same error. <ErrorResponse 
    xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
        <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>2adbe4bf-0639-5821-ad80-a88d48daa413</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>

Comment: @RajanPhatak, have you checked that using the same inputs as in the examples in the Amazon documentation, you get the same signature?

Comment: I have provided same inputs. I am not understanding where exactly i am going wrong. :(